# Disable or Enable phone radio in windows mobile 6.5.3

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5, .net-cf-3.5

I would like to enable or disable phone radio in low connectivity areas. Is it possible to do this? I am using motorola ES400 for development.

Comment: Aside from the answer below, another option is to use the vendor's device SDK (which Moto calls their EMDK ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to P/Invoke `GetDeviceList` and `ChangeRadioState` from `ossvcs.dll`.  The code to actually do this is a bit long for a SO post, so I'll leave it to you to get it worked out - it's not terribly hard (there's some [C code here](http://www.teksoftco.com/articles/article%20007/radiodevices.htm), and there's some [C# code on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103104/Radio-Power) even, I've not used it so YMMV).

Another alternative is to use the `Radios` class in the SDF, which already has these wrapped.

Answer (score 2):

First : Import these dlls

```
    [DllImport("ossvcs.dll", EntryPoint = "#276", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern uint GetWirelessDevice(ref IntPtr pDevice, int pDevVal);

    [DllImport("ossvcs.dll", EntryPoint = "#273", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern uint ChangeRadioState(ref RDD pDevice, int dwState, int saveAction);

    [DllImport("ossvcs.dll", EntryPoint = "#280", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern uint FreeDeviceList(IntPtr pDevice);
```

And here's a copy of the code I use for the Motorola MC65, which should work for yours as well.

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]
    struct RADIODEVSTATE
    {
        public const int RADIODEVICES_ON = 1;
        public const int RADIODEVICES_OFF = 0;
    }

    /*
    typedef enum _RADIODEVTYPE
    {
        RADIODEVICES_MANAGED = 1,
        RADIODEVICES_PHONE,
        RADIODEVICES_BLUETOOTH,
    } RADIODEVTYPE;
     */
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    struct RADIODEVTYPE
    {
        public const int RADIODEVICES_MANAGED = 1;
        public const int RADIODEVICES_PHONE = 2;
        public const int RADIODEVICES_BLUETOOTH = 3;
    }

    /*
    typedef enum _SAVEACTION
    {
        RADIODEVICES_DONT_SAVE = 0,
        RADIODEVICES_PRE_SAVE,
        RADIODEVICES_POST_SAVE,
    } SAVEACTION;
     */
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    struct SAVEACTION
    {
        public const int RADIODEVICES_DONT_SAVE = 0;
        public const int RADIODEVICES_PRE_SAVE = 1;
        public const int RADIODEVICES_POST_SAVE = 2;
    }

    /*
    struct RDD 
    {
        RDD() : pszDeviceName(NULL), pNext(NULL), pszDisplayName(NULL) {}
        ~RDD() { LocalFree(pszDeviceName); LocalFree(pszDisplayName); }
        LPTSTR   pszDeviceName;  // Device name for registry setting.
        LPTSTR   pszDisplayName; // Name to show the world
        DWORD    dwState;        // ON/off/[Discoverable for BT]
        DWORD    dwDesired;      // desired state - used for setting registry etc.
        RADIODEVTYPE    DeviceType;         // Managed, phone, BT etc.
        RDD * pNext;    // Next device in list
    }; //radio device details
     */
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    struct RDD
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
        public string pszDeviceName;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
        public string pszDisplayName;

        public uint dwState;
        public uint dwDesired;
        public int DeviceType;
        public IntPtr pNext;
    }


    private static bool SetDeviceState(int dwDevice, int dwState)
    {
        var pDevice = new IntPtr(0);

        //Get the first wireless device
        var result = GetWirelessDevice(ref pDevice, 0);

        if (result != 0)
            return false;

            //While we're still looking at wireless devices
            while (pDevice != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                //Marshall the pointer into a C# structure
                var device = (RDD)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(pDevice, typeof(RDD));

                //If this device is the device we're looking for
                if (device.DeviceType == dwDevice)
                {
                    //Change the state of the radio
                    result = ChangeRadioState(ref device, dwState, SAVEACTION.RADIODEVICES_PRE_SAVE);
                }

                //Set the pointer to the next device in the linked list
                pDevice = device.pNext;
            }

            //Free the list of devices
            FreeDeviceList(pDevice);

        //Turning off radios doesn't correctly report the status, so return true anyway.
        return result == 0 || dwState == RADIODEVSTATE.RADIODEVICES_OFF;
    }
```

And to turn off the phone simply call following method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Disables the phone radio on device
    /// </summary>
    public void DisablePhoneRadio()
    {
            SetDeviceState(RADIODEVTYPE.RADIODEVICES_PHONE, RADIODEVSTATE.RADIODEVICES_OFF);
    }
```

So just use whatever conditional statements are needed and call DisablePhoneRadio() whenever you need to disable it, and when enabling the phone radio simply swat out the RADIODEVSTATE.RADIODEVICES_OFF with RADIODEVSTATE.RADIODEVICES_ON like so:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Enables the phone radio on device
    /// </summary>
    public void EnablePhoneRadio()
    {
            SetDeviceState(RADIODEVTYPE.RADIODEVICES_PHONE, RADIODEVSTATE.RADIODEVICES_ON);
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread as well. Interesting take on threaded calls and monitoring the device connectivity state and powering on and off the cellular radio on windows mobile.

http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/4117749/Re-Csharp-Wrapper.aspx